# increment a variable upon calling print function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to take some action, for example increment a global variable every time Python builtin `print()` function is called? I have looked at function decorators but entirely clear on how to define for the builtin functions.

Comment: `print` is not a standard function in python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

If anyone's trying to do this in Python 3.x, consider importing `builtins`:

```
import builtins

v = 0

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    global v
    v += 1
    builtins.print(*args, **kwargs)

print('foo')   # foo
print(v == 1)  # True
print(v == 2)  # True
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just alias the `print` function, e.g. `original_print = print`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x `print` is a *statement*, not a function, so you can't change its behavior. You can use a [future statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements) to make it a function first (like in Python 3.x) and override that:

```
from __future__ import print_function

counter = 0
_print = print  # save a reference to the built-in print()

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    _print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm trying this approach. Sometimes _print(*args, **kwargs) doesn't result in any output. How can i debug this?